# How to read first n rows without loading entire file?

Tags: apache-spark

Have some XML and regular text files that are north of 2 gigs. Loading the entire file into memory everytime I want to try something out in Spark takes too long on my machine.

Is there a way to read only a portion of the file (similar to running a SQL command against a large table and only getting a few rows without it taking forever)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restrict the number of rows to n while reading a file by using `limit(n)`.

For csv files it can be done as:

```
spark.read.csv("/path/to/file/").limit(n)
```

and text files as:

```
spark.read.text("/path/to/file/").limit(n)
```

Running `explain` on the obtained dataframes show that not the whole file is loaded, here with `n=3` on an csv file:

```
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 3
...
```

Comment: This actually does not address the question. This approach actually reads in the *entire file*, creates a DataFrame with all the rows in the file, and then creates a new DataFrame with the first N rows from the first DataFrame (which is then discarded because it is no longer referenced). `limit()` is a `DataFrame` method.